# How can I tell MyCountDownTimer to quit whenever a certain activity isn't opened?

Tags: android, android-intent

The project i'm working on is an quiz with a timer on each question. for 30 seconds. I noticed that if you finish the test before the timer runs out, the timer doesn't stop running. So if you head on to another test, the notification that you haven't finished the test will popup and overide the current activity.

Here is the MyCountDownTimer Class

```
public MyCountDownTimer(TextView textCounter, long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
            this.textCounter = textCounter;
        }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {


      textCounter.setText(String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000));

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {


        Intent retryIntent = new Intent(textCounter.getContext(), Retry.class);

           if (textCounter.getContext() instanceof Test1){
               whichTest = 1;
               retryIntent.putExtra("whichTest",whichTest);
           }
        if (textCounter.getContext() instanceof Test2){
            whichTest = 2;
            retryIntent.putExtra("whichTest",whichTest);
        }

        if (textCounter.getContext() instanceof Test3){
            whichTest = 3;
            retryIntent.putExtra("whichTest",whichTest);
        }
        if (textCounter.getContext() instanceof Test4){
            whichTest = 4;
            retryIntent.putExtra("whichTest",whichTest);
        }

        if (textCounter.getContext() instanceof Test5){
            whichTest = 5;
            retryIntent.putExtra("whichTest",whichTest);
        }
        if (textCounter.getContext() instanceof Test6){
            whichTest = 6;
            retryIntent.putExtra("whichTest",whichTest);
        }
        if (textCounter.getContext() instanceof Test7){
            whichTest = 7;
            retryIntent.putExtra("whichTest",whichTest);
        }

        textCounter.getContext().startActivity(retryIntent);



}
```

Edit: Additional code
                if (textCounter==null){

```
                myCountDownTimer.onFinish();

            }


        } else  {


           // String score7S = Integer.toString(score7);
            myCountDownTimer.cancel();
            Intent intent7 = new Intent(Test7.this, UsersAnswers7.class);
            intent7.putExtra("usersAnswers7", usersAnswers7);
            intent7.putExtra("isATOF7", isATOF7);
            intent7.putExtra("score7", score7);
            startActivity(intent7);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

CountDownTimer has a cancel() method.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html#cancel()

Call that whenever your user "finishes the test" in time and onFinish() won't be called.

Comment: Can I get a small example?

Comment: You just call cancel() on your MyCountDownTimer instance. I can't be more specific because you're not showing how you're using it.